# Linux kernel SPI driver does not enable CS before writing

Tags: linux, arduino, linux-kernel

I am trying to write a kernel space SPI driver, and have it communicate with an Arduino board, as a start.
I issue simple spi_write function in kernel space. The problem I'm having is that Chip Select or Slave Select (SS) is enabled when the driver is probed. After spi_write, it is disabled and never again set to HIGH. Therefore I am only able to write once from the linux kernel SPI driver.

The driver looks like follows:

```
#define MIBI_READ(mibi_priv, reg)   ((mibi_priv)->bops->read((mibi_priv)->dev, reg))
#define MIBI_WRITE(mibi_priv, reg, val) ((mibi_priv)->bops->write((mibi_priv)->dev, reg, val))

struct spi_bus_ops {
    u16 bustype;
    int (*read)(struct device *, unsigned char);
    int (*read_block)(struct device *, unsigned char, int, void *);
    int (*write)(struct device *, unsigned char, unsigned char);
};

struct mibi {
    struct device *dev;
    const struct spi_bus_ops *bops;
};

static const struct spi_bus_ops spi_bops = {
    .bustype    = BUS_SPI,
    .write      = mibi_spi_write,
    .read       = mibi_spi_read,
    .read_block = mibi_spi_read_block,
};

static int mibi_spi_probe(struct spi_device *spi)
{
    struct mibi *mibi_priv;

    dev_info(&spi->dev, "mibi_spi probed\n");

    /* send the spi operations */
    mibi_priv = mibi_probe(&spi->dev, &spi_bops);

    if (IS_ERR(mibi_priv))
        return PTR_ERR(mibi_priv);

    /* Attach the SPI device to the private structure */
    spi_set_drvdata(spi, mibi_priv);

    dev_info(&spi->dev, "mibi_spi exited\n");

    return 0;
}

static int mibi_spi_write(struct device *dev,
                 unsigned char reg, unsigned char val)
{
    struct spi_device *spi = to_spi_device(dev);

    dev_info(dev, "mibi_spi_write entered\n");

    u8 buf[2];

    buf[0] = reg;
    buf[1] = val;

    dev_info(dev, "mibi_spi_write exited\n");

    return spi_write(spi, buf, sizeof(buf));
}

struct mibi *mibi_probe(struct device *dev,
                  const struct spi_bus_ops *bops)
{
    struct mibi *mibi_priv; /* declare our private structure */
    struct spi_device *spi = to_spi_device(dev);
    int err, ret;
    u8 revid;

    dev_info(dev, "mibi probed\n");

    /* Allocate private structure*/
    mibi_priv = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(*mibi_priv), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!mibi_priv) {
        dev_err(dev, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto err_out;
    }

    /* Initialize our private structure */
    mibi_priv->dev = dev;

    /* Store the SPI operations in our private structure */
    mibi_priv->bops = bops;

    /* Sysfs registration */
    ret = sysfs_create_group(&spi->dev.kobj, &mibi_sysfs_group);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        dev_err(dev, "Couldn't register sysfs group\n");
        return ret;
    }

    dev_info(dev, "mibi exited\n");

    return mibi_priv;

 err_out:
    return ERR_PTR(err);
}
```

Devicetree looks like follows:

```
&spi0 {
    mibi0: mibi@0 {
        compatible = "mibi";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <5000000>;
    };
    spidev0: spidev@0 {
        compatible = "spidev";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <125000000>;
    };
};
```

From a sysfs callback, I simply call `MIBI_WRITE(mibi_priv, 0x01, 0x06);`.

Arduino side looks like follows:

```
//Initialize SPI slave.
void SlaveInit(void) {
  // Initialize SPI pins.
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT);
  // Enable SPI as slave.
  SPCR = (1 << SPE);
}

// SPI Transfer.
byte SPItransfer(byte value) {
  SPDR = value;
  while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
  delay(10);
  return SPDR;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SlaveInit();
}

void loop()
{
// Slave Enabled?
  if (!digitalRead(SS)) {
    // Yes, first time?
    if (SSlast != LOW) {
      // Yes, take MISO pin.
      pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
      Serial.println("***Slave Enabled.");
      // Write -1 slave response code and receive master command code
      byte rx = SPItransfer(255);
      Serial.println("Initial -1 slave response code sent");
      Serial.println("rx:" + String(rx) + ".");
      // Update SSlast.
      SSlast = LOW;
    }
  }
  else {
    // No, first time?
    if (SSlast != HIGH) {
      // Yes, release MISO pin.
      pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
      Serial.println("Slave Disabled.");
      // Update SSlast.
      SSlast = HIGH;
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to write once from Linux kernel to Arduino correctly, but then the SS is always low so I can not write anymore. What do you think I am missing here? Is there a way to make sure that SS changes as I call "spi_write"?
(Might the problem related to having spidev and mibi both attached to the same CS?)

I would appreciate general advice to achieving this as well as support for the solution to my problem. Thank you.

**EDIT** Chip Select is not modified still, even that I converted the driver to use Regmap-SPI. The situation is as before. I am able to write once to the Arduino. But Chip Select does not change after driver is probed. How do I handle Chip Select in Linux SPI subsystem? Find the final state of the driver as follows:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/spi/spi.h>
#include <linux/iio/iio.h>
#include <linux/regmap.h>

/* Top level struct */
struct mibi_state {
    struct regmap *regmap;
    struct spi_device *spi;
    u8 buffer[4];
};

/* IIO-Userspace communication channels */
#define MIBI_NUM_IIO_CHANNELS 2
static const struct iio_chan_spec mibi_channels[MIBI_NUM_IIO_CHANNELS] = {
    {
        .type       = IIO_VOLTAGE,
        .indexed    = 1,
        .output     = 1,
        .channel    = 0,
        .info_mask_separate = BIT(IIO_CHAN_INFO_RAW),
    },
    {
        .type       = IIO_VOLTAGE,
        .indexed    = 1,
        .output     = 1,
        .channel    = 1,
        .info_mask_separate = BIT(IIO_CHAN_INFO_RAW),
    },
};

/* IIO-Userspace communication read callback */
static int mibi_read_raw(struct iio_dev *indio_dev,
    struct iio_chan_spec const *chan, int *val, int *val2, long mask)
{
    int ret;
    struct mibi_state *st = iio_priv(indio_dev);

    dev_info(&st->spi->dev, "Entered read_raw\n");

    u32 read_value;

    switch (mask) {
        case IIO_CHAN_INFO_RAW:

            ret = regmap_read(st->regmap, 0x01, &read_value);
            if (ret) {
                dev_err(&st->spi->dev, "Error reading in read_raw callback\n");
                return ret;
            }
            dev_info(&st->spi->dev, "regmap_read 0x01 %d\n",read_value);

            *val  = read_value;

            dev_info(&st->spi->dev, "read_raw value %d\n", *val);

            return IIO_VAL_INT;

        default:
            return -EINVAL;
    }
}

/* IIO-Userspace communication write callback */
static int mibi_write_raw(struct iio_dev *indio_dev,
                struct iio_chan_spec const *chan,
                int val, int val2, long mask)
{
    struct mibi_state *st = iio_priv(indio_dev);

    u8 value;
    value = 0;
    dev_info(&st->spi->dev, "Entered write_raw\n");

    switch (mask) {
        case IIO_CHAN_INFO_RAW:
            value = val;
            dev_info(&st->spi->dev, "regmap_write 0x01 %d\n",value);
            return regmap_write(st->regmap, 0x01, value);
        default :
            return -EINVAL;
    }
}

/* IIO-Userspace communication */
static const struct iio_info mibi_info = {
    .read_raw = &mibi_read_raw,
    .write_raw = &mibi_write_raw,
};

/* Regmap-SPI config */
static const struct regmap_config mibi_spi_regmap_config = {
    .reg_bits = 8,
    .val_bits = 8,
     /* Setting bits 7 and 6 enables multiple-byte read */
    .read_flag_mask = BIT(7) | BIT(6),
};

/* Probe */
static int mibi_probe(struct spi_device *spi)
{
    struct iio_dev *indio_dev;
    struct mibi_state *st;
    struct regmap *regmap;
    int err;
    int ret;
    dev_info(&spi->dev, "mibi_probe() entered.\n");

    const struct spi_device_id *id = spi_get_device_id(spi);

    /* Allocate IIO */
    indio_dev = devm_iio_device_alloc(&spi->dev, sizeof(*st));
    if (indio_dev == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;

    st = iio_priv(indio_dev);

    /* Allocate regmap */
    regmap = devm_regmap_init_spi(spi, &mibi_spi_regmap_config);
    if (IS_ERR(regmap)) {
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Error initializing spi regmap: %ld\n",
            PTR_ERR(regmap));
        return PTR_ERR(regmap);
    }

    /* Populate top level struct */
    st->regmap = regmap;
    st->spi = spi;

    /* Populate IIO struct */
    indio_dev->dev.parent = &spi->dev;
    indio_dev->channels = mibi_channels;
    indio_dev->info = &mibi_info;
    indio_dev->name = id->name;
    indio_dev->num_channels = MIBI_NUM_IIO_CHANNELS;
    indio_dev->modes = INDIO_DIRECT_MODE;

    /* IIO Register */
    err = devm_iio_device_register(&spi->dev, indio_dev);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    ret = regmap_write(st->regmap, 0x01, 0x06);
    if (ret < 0) {
        dev_err(&spi->dev, "Error writing to device: %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}


static const struct of_device_id mibi_dt_ids[] = {
    { .compatible = "mozcelikors,mibi", },
    { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, mibi_dt_ids);

static const struct spi_device_id mibi_id[] = {
    { .name = "mibi", },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(spi, mibi_id);


static struct spi_driver mibi_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name   = "mibi",
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = mibi_dt_ids,
    },
    .probe      = mibi_probe,
    .id_table   = mibi_id,
};

module_spi_driver(mibi_driver);
```

Comment: What about `dtparam=spi=on`?

Comment: @stark I think that is only a Raspberry Pi configuration. In my case SPI subsystem is already enabled.

Comment: I completely don't get the code. How those SPI operations are supposed to work? Where are the sysfs attributes in the code? How it is even compile? Btw, why do you need those sysfs attributes?

Comment: @0andriy Of course I did not publish the complete code. I need sysfs attributes for testing my code at runtime. I suggest you read about spi_bus_ops.

Comment: @0andriy Please find here an example of spi_bus_ops https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/adxl34x-spi_8c_source.html . I used the same skeleton as this one. write works but only once, I think my problem is related to CS. Or if you have a better suggestion of dealing with SPI driver, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: The idea behind that custom structure there is to get an abstraction in bus connection. Are you going to enable anything else than SPI?

Comment: The main file is what you need to consider, but it’s an old driver which does not utilize all best practices of modern kernel programming. Moreover it uses custom ABI (sysfs). You took really **bad example**.

Comment: @0andriy Not really, I am just interested in creating an SPI client driver skeleton at the moment. Do you have a suggestion where I could see a good example?

Comment: Find a driver that uses regmap SPI API. And for debug purposes that API already has a capability to dump registers. Look under *drivers/iio/* for a start. Btw, there is a modern driver for this chip. The old is left for compatibility purpose with legacy systems.

Comment: @0andriy I see, Thanks for the advice, will do.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/accel/adxl345_spi.c

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. May I ask how do I read and write with this regmap structure? The thing is, I considered using regmap but I then thought I'd start with a basic spi driver structure, which like you said, turned out to be of ancient times.

Comment: Use `regmap_read()` and `regmap_write()`. Look at the core driver of that sensor in the same folder.

Comment: @0andriy Even with regmap & iio example, Chip Select does not change after driver is probed and data is written once. I wonder how Chip Select works with Linux kernel SPI subsystem. I am editing question to add the new driver.